# ROS Answers SE migration: ROS2 or ROS 2?

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have seen a lot of discussions around this topic and must say I do agree and prefer to call it ROS2.
Simply for the reason that in the Terminal you can't just write

```
$ ros 2 service list
```

and expect it to work. So it would be

```
$ ros_2 service list
```

or maybe even with an escape character

```
$ ros\ 2 service list
```

So let's just agree we stick with ROS2 or ros2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/407627/ros2-or-ros-2?/) by [PointCloud](https://answers.ros.org/users/73699/pointcloud/) on ROS Answers with karma: 120 on 2022-10-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It just simply is 'ROS 2'.

The developers of ROS 2 have named it ROS 2, as evidenced by its usage on its homepage https://www.ros.org/ and throughout all documentation. The name of a command line tool that is only a small part of the full ROS 2 ecosystem does not change that. Similarly, you use `python3` or maybe `python3.10` rather than `python\ 3` or `python\ 3.10` to work with Python 3 or Python 3.10, and you don't write those Python3 or Python3.10.

Having said that, everybody will get it when you use ROS2, or Ros2 even, like anybody will understand when you use 'Coca Cola' or 'Micro Soft' (though perhaps with judgment :) ), and anybody making a big point of it, in any case in conversation and out side of official documentation, can be safely ignored IMHO.

---

Originally posted by [sgvandijk](https://answers.ros.org/users/72841/sgvandijk/) with karma: 649 on 2022-10-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [PointCloud](https://answers.ros.org/users/73699/pointcloud/) on 2022-10-08**:
Fair and valid point @sgvandijk
Haven't viewed it from that angle, but I agree.

Thank you for taking the time to clarify. I will close this and marked it as answer!
Cheers